# Difference between grouping parentheses and `begin` ... `end`

Tags: ruby, parentheses, control-structure

What is the difference between parentheses used for grouping:

```rb
(some_method_chain; another_method_chain)

2 * (3 + 4) # => 14
```

and the `begin` ... `end` structure:

```rb
begin some_method_chain; another_method_chain end

2 * begin 3 + 4 end # => 14
```

I notice that only the latter can be used to enclose a `rescue` construction. Are there any other differences?

Comment: "to enclose a rescue construction" - the modifier version? Or the regular one?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not sure how they differ in a modifier version of a rescue construction. I meant the regular one.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It looks like the latter one can be used as well: `begin;
  raise "foo" rescue begin puts "bar" end;
end
 # >> bar`

Comment: This is still a simple modifier, no? :shrug:

Comment: Of course, parentheses don't support `ensure`: `begin true ensure a = 'cat' end #=> true; a #=> "cat"`. I noticed nesting is not a problem. I've never seen `begin...end` in-line.

Comment: sawa, in your previous comment you don't seem to need either semicolon. `begin raise "foo" rescue begin puts "bar" end end` seems to work fine.

Comment: The fact that `begin..end` can be used in-line means that one can write lines that look a lot line in-line rescue clauses but permit the error class to be specified: `begin 4/0 rescue ZeroDivisionError; 'whoops' end #=> "whoops"`.

Comment: Another one is when the while modifier is used: with begin you have Ruby's weird do while loop meaning the body expression is evaluated at least once. Not the case with parentheses!

Comment: @cremno, Tuesday is my dense-day. Can you give an example.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `begin p 1 end while false` prints 1 but `(p 1) while false` prints nothing.

Comment: Some of the comments here seem to have good points. I would love to read them as individual answers.

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps someone could gather them up into a single answer, possibly a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). sawa?